# I get an out of range error showing using under an OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using this code to show all the users in an OU:

```
private void btn_objecten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_objecten.Items.Clear();
    //string ou = "DC=" + lv_rootOU.SelectedItem.ToString();
    DirectoryEntry verbinding = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=Test,dc=roel,dc=gui");
    DirectorySearcher zoekOU = new DirectorySearcher(verbinding);

    zoekOU.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

    zoekOU.PropertiesToLoad.Add("user");
    zoekOU.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";

    foreach (SearchResult deResult in zoekOU.FindAll())
    {
        string ouNaam = deResult.Properties["user"][0].ToString();            
        lb_objecten.Items.Add(ouNaam);   
    }
}
```

But I am getting an out of range error executing the code.
Can someone help?

Comment: I would check if deResult.Properties has any values

Comment: Tahnk you for the response. I am new to this. Can you tell me how or where I can find how that works?

Comment: 1. Set propertiestoload to correct value. User is a class - not a property. Specify attributes that you need to load or keep it empty to load all user attributes. 2. Set pagesize to some value (e. g. 1000) to enable pagination. Otherwise if your ou contains more than 1000 objects you will be in trouble. 3. Replace objectcategory with objectclass in search filter. 4. Check if attribute exists in searchentry before accessing it

Answer (score 0):

I used this to check if it is empty, I dont know if i am using it right, but the error is gone, but is doesn't show any results:

```
private void btn_objecten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb_objecten.Items.Clear();
        //string ou = "DC=" + lv_rootOU.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DirectoryEntry verbinding = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=Test,dc=roel,dc=gui");
        DirectorySearcher zoekOU = new DirectorySearcher(verbinding);

        zoekOU.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

        zoekOU.PropertiesToLoad.Add("user");
        zoekOU.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";

        foreach (SearchResult deResult in zoekOU.FindAll())
        {
            string ouNaam = deResult.Properties["user"][0].ToString();
            if (deResult.Equals(0))
            {
                lb_objecten.Items.Add(ouNaam);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void btn_objecten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_objecten.Items.Clear();
    //string ou = "DC=" + lv_rootOU.SelectedItem.ToString();
    DirectoryEntry verbinding = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=Test,dc=roel,dc=gui");
    DirectorySearcher zoekOU = new DirectorySearcher(verbinding);

    zoekOU.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

    zoekOU.PropertiesToLoad.Add("user");
    zoekOU.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";

    foreach (SearchResult deResult in zoekOU.FindAll())
    {
        if (deResult.Properties["user"].Any())
        {
          string ouNaam = deResult.Properties["user"][0].ToString();            
          lb_objecten.Items.Add(ouNaam);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It throws me an error: does not contain a definition for 'Any'

Comment: @roeludh Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, or just use `deResult.Properties.Contains("user")`, which will achieve the same thing.